# Update an item of an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a document looking like this:

```
{
  name: "Name1",
  values: [ 
    { type: "type1", value: 123 },
    { type: "type2", value: 456 },
    { type: "type3", value: 666 },
    { type: "type3", value: 777 }
  ]
}
```

There are many of them. How do I update all of them so that each document has only one `values.type3` which is bigger than another one:

```
{
  name: "Name1",
  values: [ 
    { type: "type1", value: 123 },
    { type: "type2", value: 456 },
    { type: "type3", value: 777 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is the values array sorted on the basis of value field.??

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset isn't too large you can run this from the mongo shell:

```
db.collection.find({ 'values.type': 'type3' }).forEach( function(doc) {
   var values = [];
   var tmp = { value: 0 };

   for( var v in doc.values )
   {
      v = doc.values[v];
      if ( v.type !== "type3" ) 
         values.push( v );
      else if ( v.value > tmp.value )
         tmp = v;
   }

   values.push( tmp );
   doc.values = values;

   db.collection.save( doc );
});
```

Just change out the collection names, proper values etc...

Comment: why `find({ 'values.type': 'type3' })`? It must find all the documetns.

Comment: @MariusKavansky - you don't need to pass any criteria to the find if you don't want to.  My answer was just tailored to the example in your question.  It would be trivial to change it to look for all matching keys and grab the highest value if you're not just worried about `type3` as in your example.